# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos de mi Lista Enlazada desde otra clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy tratando de acceder a los datos de mi Lista Enlazada (dato1 y dato2) dentro del método `calcularVariables` desde la clase `RegresionLineal`. Al momento de verificar si el dato1 y el dato2 tienen información con unos `print`, me imprime:

```
None
None
```

Sabiendo que ya han sido agregado los datos a mi lista que  comprobé con el método `obtenerNodos` que tengo en la clase Lista Enlazada.

No sé porque me devuelven None si se supone que ya están los datos en la lista.

Debajo mi clase RegresionLineal

```
class RegresionLineal:

    xi = 0
    yi = 0
    lista = ListaEnlazada()

    def __init__(self, proxy):
       self.proxy = proxy

    def calcularVariables(self, lista):

       nodoActual = self.lista.nodoInicio
       while nodoActual.siguienteNodo != None:
           xi = nodoActual.dato1
           yi = nodoActual.dato2

       print(nodoActual.dato1)
       print(nodoActual.dato2)
```

Clase LecturaArchivo donde agrego los datos a la Lista Enlazada

```
class LecturaArchivo:

    proxy = 0.0
    listaEnlazada = ListaEnlazada()
    regresionLineal = RegresionLineal(proxy)



    nombreArchivo = input('Nombre del archivo: ')
    archivo = open(nombreArchivo, "r")
    lineas = archivo.read()
    datos = lineas.split(',')

    for dato in datos:
       xTemporal = float(datos[0])
       yTemporal = float(datos[1])

       listaEnlazada.agregarNodoFinal((xTemporal), (yTemporal))


    regresionLineal.calcularVariables(listaEnlazada.obtenerNodos())
```

**Clase ListaEnlazada**

```
class ListaEnlazada:
      def __init__(self):
      self.nodoInicio = Nodo()

   def tamano(self):
      actual = self.nodoInicio
      total = 0
      while actual.siguienteNodo != None:
          total += 1
          actual = actual.siguienteNodo
      return total

   def agregarNodoFinal(self, dato1, dato2):
      nodoNuevo = Nodo(dato1, dato2)
      actual = self.nodoInicio
      while actual.siguienteNodo is not None:
          actual = actual.siguienteNodo
      actual.siguienteNodo = nodoNuevo

   def obtenerNodos(self):
      datos = []
      nodo = self.nodoInicio
      while nodo.siguienteNodo is not None:
          nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo
      datos.append(nodo.dato1)
      datos.append(nodo.dato2)
      return datos


  def vacia(self):
      if self.nodoInicio == None:
         return True
      else:
         return False
```

Comment: Hola Hector ! Bienvenido. Puede darnos la clase `ListaEnlazada` ? Es para verificar si `.agregarNodoFinal` agrega cualquier cosa efectivamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya edite el contenido y ya esta la lista enlazada

Comment: Pienso que has olvidado ciertas `self.blablabla_nodo`

Comment: puedes ser un poco más especifico? te lo agradecería

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no estas llenando la lista de la clase RegresionLineal. Por eso cuando accedes a al método calcularVariables te da vacio.Tal vez la confusión este en que la clase RegresionLineal tienes una variable lista, que es la que referencias en nodoActual = self.lista.nodoInicio pero no es la que inicializas cuando pasas lista como parámetro a la función   def calcularVariables(self, lista). Checa esto y comentanos como te fue. Revisa también porque al parecer la función listaEnlazada.obtenerNodos() te devuelve los dos últimos valores del último nodo, no se si ese es el comportamiento que estas buscando, pero definitivamente por este lugar esta el problema.